# Strange output of btrfs fi df after converting from RAID0 to RAID1

Tags: filesystem, raid, btrfs

I just converted my 3 disk btrfs filesystem from RAID0 to RAID1 and balanced it.

At first the data was all in the RAID0 filesystem, so running btrfs filesystem df showed something like this: (XX are because I don't remember the exact sizes)

```
Data, RAID1: total=4.00GB, used=4.00GB
Data, RAID0: total=2.XXTB, used=2.XXTB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MB, used=340.00KB
System: total=4.00MB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID1: total=5.00GB, used=2.54GB
```

The data was transfered between filesystems. So it seemed everything was working perfectly. However the balance operation finished and I am left with this:

```
Data, RAID1: total=2.35TB, used=2.32TB
Data, RAID0: total=2.00GB, used=2.00GB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MB, used=340.00KB
System: total=4.00MB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID1: total=5.00GB, used=2.54GB
```

I don't know why I still have 2 GB in a RAID0 configuration. How can I get rid of it? I have tried rebooting in case some further cleaunp was needed, but to no avail. Any tips I can try?

Also can anybody explain why I have two System entries?

I have tried running `btrfs balance status /storage` and there is no balance operation still in process.

I am running a full `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /status` again and will see if this fixes it.

---

UPDATE: After struggling and trying everything I opted to take all of my data out of the disks and format them. I did not find any solution to the problem.

Comment: Just curiosity: the `XX` in `2.XX TB` is `btrfs` original output, or it is your addition? I'm asking because I've never seen that.

Comment: Try another balance with [the `profiles` parameter](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters), to select (only) the RAID0 data for rebalancing. I've never used it myself, but I guess you may use `-dprofiles=raid0 -dconvert=raid1` or something along the lines of that.

Comment: Also, ensure you are using the latest kernel and btrfs-tools. Btrfs is getting a lot of bugfixes between releases.

Comment: Maybe the balance is not complete? You may check [with `btrfs fi balance status`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/btrfs.8.html)

Comment: Answered some of the questions in my edit. It seems my question was not very clear. Thanks guys!

Comment: I have the same issue with `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1` I always have around 100GB left Raid0 Data on both drives.
Did it solve it for you?

Comment: Please add output of `sudo btrfs fi usage /storage`

Comment: And what is the kernel and btrfs-progs version?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data in question were in use during convert or something like that. Anyway, it can be fixed without redoing/reformatting everything by running

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,soft -mconvert=raid1,soft /status
```

over and over until it looks good. I had the same problem, first balance left some data in old profile, second balance fixed it and everything was in new profile.